# Tkinter Button getting a Button to Accept Valid Args

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

As it stands the code in the below line is not accepting the Tkinter Entry variables `price_range`, `num_of_beds`, and `county` above it. I have tried several different configurations but to no avail. The logic here is that these variables will be called by a function that exists above the class (this portion does work fine). I am noticing that the `price_range` variable is stored as PY_VAR0 but the `.get()` doesn't seem to resolve this issue. The line in question:

```
 Button(window, text="Run Program!", command= lambda : run1.runBot(str(price_range.get()), str(num_of_beds.get()), str(county.get()))).grid(row=7,column=2, padx= (60,5), pady=5)
```

The traceback:

```
Button(window, text="Run Program!", command= lambda : run1.runBot(str(price_range.get()), str(num_of_beds.get()), str(county.get()))).grid(row=7,column=2, padx= (60,5), pady=5)

NameError: name 'price_range' is not defined
```

The code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

username = ********
password = "*********"

class Bot:
    def runBot(self, price_range, num_of_beds, county):

        driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Matt\\Documents\\WebDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
        #profile = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Matt\\Documents\\WebDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")

        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        prefs = {"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 1,
                     "download.default_directory": 
                                "C:\\Users\\Matt\\Documents\\Splitt",
                     "directory_upgrade": True}
        
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
        driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Matt\\Documents\\WebDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
        driver.get("https://www.stellarmls.com/")
        driver.maximize_window()


        username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("loginid")
        username_textbox.send_keys(username)

        password_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
        password_textbox.send_keys(password)

        login_button = driver.find_element_by_id("dropdownMenuButton")
        login_button.submit()

        tab_url = 'https://dashboard.stellarmls.com/layouts'
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

        driver.get(tab_url)

        tab_url = 'https://stellar.mlsmatrix.com/matrix/?f='
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        driver.get(tab_url)

        tab_url = 'https://stellar.mlsmatrix.com/Matrix/Search/Residential/Quick'
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        driver.get(tab_url)
        

        driver.find_element_by_id('Fm23_Ctrl88_TB').send_keys(price_range)
        driver.find_element_by_id('Fm23_Ctrl99_TB').send_keys(num_of_beds)
        driver.find_element_by_id('Fm23_Ctrl2096_LB_TB').send_keys(county)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="m_ucResultsPageTabs_m_lbMapTab"]/span/i').click()

run1 = Bot()


class PropertyCalculator:

    window = Tk()
    window.title("MLS Property ROI Calculator")
    
    Label(window, text="Price Range (ex: 100-400)").grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
    Label(window, text="Number of Bedrooms").grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
    #TODO: create town filter
    Label(window, text="County").grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
    Label(window, text=None).grid(row=4,column=1) # space between inputs and outputs
    
    #Variables to store inputs
    price_range = StringVar()
    num_of_beds = StringVar()
    county = StringVar()


            
    #Text boxes to hold inputs and outputs
    ttk.Entry(window, textvariable = price_range,
          justify=RIGHT).grid(row=1,column=2, padx=(0,5))
    ttk.Entry(window, textvariable = num_of_beds, 
          justify=RIGHT).grid(row=2,column=2)
    ttk.Entry(window, textvariable = county, 
          justify=RIGHT).grid(row=3,column=2)
    print("the price: ", price_range)

    Button(window, text="Run Program!", command= lambda : run1.runBot(price_range.get(),num_of_beds.get(), county.get())).grid(row=7,column=2, padx= (60,5), pady=5)
    window.mainloop()


execute(window)
WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="m_lnkCheckAllLink"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="m_lbExport"]/span'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="m_ddExport"]'))).send_keys('m')
WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="m_btnExport"]'))).click()
```

Comment: you have not provided anything for `price_range` you need something like `price_range=[1,2,3]`

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: your error says 'window' not defined, check your spellings.  This code runs fine for me, can't comment further without you providing the code the way you wrote it in your project. Also, note that `price_range.get()`  returns a string so there is no point in using `str()`.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors. They aren't searchable, copyable, and the visually impaired can't see them at all.

Comment: OP updated with full length of code. Image removed. The issue is definitely coming from the price_range not being defined. Refer to OP trackback for the details on that. Thanks!

Comment: `PropertyCalculator.price_range.get()` similarly for others

Comment: Traceback: NameError: name 'PropertyCalculator' is not defined. Do I need to make an adjustment to the way the class structure is set or was it working on your end?

Comment: why don't you place them under `__init__()`?

Comment: Place price_range = StringVar()..etc in __init__()?

Comment: @Mattr42 everything under that class under `__init__()` and create an instance of that class  `PropertyCalculator()`

Comment: That worked. Working class added to OP. For future educational reference for anyone in the same boat. Thanks @JacksonPro !

Comment: No answers in the question please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.